# Java generic array from null generic type

Tags: java, generics

Consider the Array.newInstance static method as a way of creating a generic type array in Java.
What I'm failing to see how to do is create a generic array from a null generic type argument:

```
/**
* Creates and fills a generic array with the given item
*/
public static <T> T[] create(T item, int length)
{
   T[] result = (T[]) Array.newInstance(item.getClass(), length);

   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      result[i] = item;

   return result;
}
```

The above works when I call e.g. create("abc", 10); I'm getting a String[] of length 10 with "abc" in all positions of the array. 
But how could I make a null string argument return a String array of length 10 and null in all positions?

e.g.

```
String nullStr = null;
String[] array = create(nullStr, 10); // boom! NullPointerException
```

Is there perhaps a  way to get the class of "item" without using one of its members (as it's null)?
I know I can just new up an array *String[] array = new String[10]*, but that's not the point.

Thanks

Comment: Not possible in that case -- only type information left *would* have been with `item` (but this information isn't if it's null, naturally :-). This could be done with taking a [Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instead or, perhaps, just  `create(SomeDefault, 10)`, e.g. `create("", 10)`. FYI: C# (not Java) has [reified types](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/11/reified-generics-for-java.html) and supports `typeof(T)`, among other things. Oh, check out the link to reified types which also talks about type erasure :-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is useful.

```
public static <T> T[] create(Class<T> clazz, int length)
{
   T[] result = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, length);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: that still throws a NullPointerException if clazz = null

Comment: @pablochan "Naturally" :-) But the difference is there is a class accessible for a given type. It's just the callers responsibility to pass the "manifest" through.

Comment: @pablochan Sure it does. `String x[] = create(String.class, 10);` The difference is the caller *knows* the type of T and isn't subject to type-erase rules at that point.

Comment: @pst: not a good example considering what the OP wants to do (create(null, 10))

Comment: @pablochan The type-erasure bit is still important. While more convoluted, it's possible to get type `String` back from type `String[]` -- that is, the information *is still available*. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType().

Comment: There is obviously a conceptual error in OP's code, so most probably (create(null, 10)) is not exactly what he wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, you can't call:

```
create(null, 10)
```

because your code can't determine the type (it ends up calling `null.getClass()` => NPE).

You could pass the class separately:

```
public static <T> T[] create(Class<T> type, int length, T fillValue)
{
   T[] result = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, length);

   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      result[i] = fillValue;

   return result;
}

// Some optional convenience signatures:

public static <T> T[] create(Class<T> type, int length) {
    return create(type, length, null);
}

public static <T> T[] create(T fillValue, int length) {
    if (fillValue == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("fillValue cannot be null");
    }
    return create(fillValue.getClass(), length, fillValue);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = create(String.class, 10, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not change the method to take a Class object instead, and just directly pass in `String.class`? Java can't get the class type of `null` because it has no class type! Any object can be null.